# access app controller scope inside custom directive in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to this so sorry if I'm asking something obvious.
 I have an app with controller holding some config variables in scope. I have a custom directive used inside ng-repeat that will have to make use of this config.
 For debugging purposes I need the changes to config bee reflected inside the directive. How can I achieve this.
What I have so far is not working my pointsmap is undefined

```
       angular.module('demo', [])
      .directive('demoDir', function () {
          var dirController = ['$scope', function ($scope) {
              $scope.totalPoints = 0;

              $scope.$watch('person', function(newVal, oldVal){
                  resetPoints(newVal);
              }, true);

              function resetPoints(pPerson){
                   $scope.totalPoints = $pointsMap['VIP'] * pPerson.points ;
              } 
          return {
              restrict: 'E',   
              scope: {
                  person: '=' ,
                  pointsMap : '='
              },
              controller: dirController, 
              template: '<span> {{totalPoints}}</span>'
         }
      })
      .controller('mainAppController', function ($compile, $scope, $q ) { 
         /*CONFIG */
          $scope.points = {
                  'VIP': 8.50,  
                  'Standard': 7.50,     
          };
      });
      <demoDir person='myobject' pointsMap='points' />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any particular reason why you want your directive to have isolated scope? If there is no restriction to use isolated scope, you can simply make the scope of the directive as false(now directive will use parent scope)

```
        angular.module('demo', [])
  .directive('demoDir', function () {
      var dirController = ['$scope', function ($scope) {
          $scope.totalPoints = 0;

          $scope.$watch('person', function(newVal, oldVal){
              resetPoints(newVal);
          }, true);

          function resetPoints(pPerson){
               $scope.totalPoints = $pointsMap['VIP'] * pPerson.points ;
          } 
      return {
          restrict: 'E',   
          scope: false,
          controller: dirController, 
          link: function(scope, element, attrs){
              //scope.points should be available
          }
          template: '<span> {{totalPoints}}</span>'
     }
  })
  .controller('mainAppController', function ($compile, $scope, $q ) { 
     /*CONFIG */
      $scope.points = {
              'VIP': 8.50,  
              'Standard': 7.50,     
      };
  });

  //assuming that your directive is housed inside the mainAppController
  <div ng-controller="mainAppController">
    <demoDir/>
  </div>
```

You will also have access to the parent scope properties in the directive's link function if you want to use.

Comment: Thank you this worked. I thought I will have to create an isolated scope because of the ng-repeat. Somehow I understood  it creates a new scope with copy of values. I tested and the config is available in my directive after applying your change.All changes to config in parent scope are visible in my directive. Thank you so much

Comment: Using parent scope in directive is quite easy and gets job done. However if you want to make a reuseable directive you can't rely on the parent scope too much and must use isolated scope instead. This article has nice info on creating isolated scope with some custom bindings(one way & two way) to the parent scope [https://blog.umur.io/2013/07/02/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/]